# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when trying to display object

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, pygame

I'm tring to create a menu for a small program, which displays [this image](https://rlv.zcache.com/weird_science_statuette-rb2a7e177fd8e4f69a512cc7fe8cf8f03_x7sai_8byvr_324.jpg). I'm using [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-images-pygame/). My code looks like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

height = 1366 #The height and width of our window
width = 769

window = pygame.display.set_mode((height,width)) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Score")

white = (255,255,255) #This block defines all the colors in (R,G,B) format

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False

flask = pygame.image.load('flask.jpg') #This block is for loading all images

def flask(x_f,y_f):
    window.blit(flask(x_f,y_f))
x_f = (width * 0.45)
y_f = (height * 0.8)

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    window.fill(white)
    flask(x_f,y_f)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

However, I keep getting a runtime error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. These are on lines 19 (3 times) and 29 (once). I'm jst wondering what exactly I'm doing wrong, since I've been following the tutorial closely.

Comment: You can't use the name `flask` for both the image, and the function to display the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the `flask` function calls itself inside of its function body again and again until the maximum recursion depth of 1000 recursions (default value) is exceeded.

Give the image a different name and then blit it in the `flask` function.

```
# Use the `convert` method to improve the performance.
flask_image = pygame.image.load('flask.jpg').convert()

def flask(x_f, y_f):
    window.blit(flask_image, (x_f, y_f))
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I also forgot to put a comma in the window.blit line!